# Easy way to insert Org options?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I really cannot bear to memorize so many options' name for Org-mode just like learning English vocabulary. For example: `#+ATTR_LATEX:`, `#+tblname:`, `#+CAPTION` for tables, `#+ATTR_HTML:` for HTML exporting.

In Org-mode, what I've known to do something similar to this are:

1. Block complete: enter `<s` press `TAB` to expand to a `#+BEGIN_SRC ... #+END_SRC` block. (or `<e`, `<q`....etc.)
2. Property name complete: `C-c C-x p` to insert property.

But, is there any built-in function to aid user to input/complete **options**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such in-buffer options, type `#+` and then `M-TAB` gives you a list of completions.  This should be bound to `pcomplete` by default in `org-mode`.  Another standard keybinding provided is `C-M-i`.

Alternatively, you can set options for a particular export route by using `C-c C-e #` and tab completing to get the export backend.

The section "Export settings" in the Org Manual describes this reasonably well.

Comment: M-TAB is captured by flyspell on my system. Can you tell what function is called by that keybinding on your system?

Comment: @mankoff - information added to my answer