# Company-mode completion for Org keywords

Tags: org-mode, company-mode

Org mode has completion for all keywords via `pcomplete`, as noted by [Andrew Swann](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5865/10269).

However, Company does not seem to pick up on these keywords. Calling `company-complete` on the following, where `|` represents point, brings up a list of English vocabulary words instead of Org keywords:

```
#+|
```

Is it possible for Company to do Org-specific completion *in addition to* the helpful textual completion that it normally does?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`company-mode` has `company-capf`. So the easiest way is adding `pcomplete-completions-at-point` to `completion-at-point-functions`:

```
(defun my-org-mode-hook ()
  (add-hook 'completion-at-point-functions 'pcomplete-completions-at-point nil t))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my-org-mode-hook)
```

Make sure `company-capf` is in the list of `company-backends`.

Comment: Thanks, that works, if somewhat imperfectly. The problem is that the `#+` is not considered for the completion, so I still have to type at least 3 letters for Company to complete (this is likely customizable, but 3's a good number in most cases for performance). So instead of `#+NAMES:` I can type `#+NAM` and save 3 letters.

Comment: Personally I have a key binding(`control+tab`) for `company-complete`. In that case, you can type `control+tab` after "#+" and `company` should be able to give all possible completions. You can also write a simple company backend that recognizes the "^#+" as the prefix in order to begin completion.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by a comment from @cutejumper, I went ahead and wrote a simple company backend that recognizes the `^#+` prefix to start using `pcomplete`.

```
(defun org-keyword-backend (command &optional arg &rest ignored)
  (interactive (list 'interactive))
  (cl-case command
    (interactive (company-begin-backend 'org-keyword-backend))
    (prefix (and (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
                 (cons (company-grab-line "^#\\+\\(\\w*\\)" 1)
                       t)))
    (candidates (mapcar #'upcase
                        (cl-remove-if-not
                         (lambda (c) (string-prefix-p arg c))
                         (pcomplete-completions))))
    (ignore-case t)
    (duplicates t)))
```

Use it with `(add-to-list 'company-backends 'org-keyword-backend)`

If you want it to wait a certain number of characters into the keyword before offering completion, change line 7 from `t` to the number you want.

If you want it to wait according to `company-minimum-prefix-length`, change lines 6 / 7 from `(cons (company-grab-line ...) t)` to just `(company-grab-line ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

After trying the accepted solution a while back (which ended up not working for me) and then giving up after about 6 months, I went back and found a simple solution.

```
(defun trigger-org-company-complete ()
  "Begins company-complete in org-mode buffer after pressing #+ chars."
  (interactive)
  (if (string-equal "#" (string (preceding-char)))
    (progn
      (insert "+")
      (company-complete))
    (insert "+")))

(eval-after-load 'org '(define-key org-mode-map
               (kbd "+") 'trigger-org-company-complete))
```

While this is certainly hacky, it's been working well for me, and it didn't require doing any complex parsing.

This works by only calling the function when the `+` character is entered in an org-mode buffer. Then, `trigger-org-company-complete` checks the preceding character, and if it's a `#` character, the `+` character is inserted and `company-complete` is called. If the previous character is not `#`, the `+` is only inserted, and everything behaves as normal.

You can see the behavior below. When just entering the `#` character, nothing happens. When `#` precedes a `+`, `company-complete` is triggered, and when just a `+` character is entered, nothing happens.

(I zoomed in a lot, which is why it's distorted)

[image]

[image]

[image]