# How to include org-mode easy templates into company-mode completions?

Tags: org-mode, company-mode

Within `org-mode`, I use [easy templates](http://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-Templates.html) a lot. But I also use `company-mode` and easy templates are not listed there, even though I've managed to add support for some of the `org-mode` keywords (see [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21173/12336)). Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add your own completion function to `completion-at-point-functions` and add `company-capf` to `company-backends`:

```el
(defun org-easy-template--completion-table (str pred action)
  (pcase action
    (`nil (try-completion  str org-structure-template-alist pred))
    (`t   (all-completions str org-structure-template-alist pred))))

(defun org-easy-template--annotation-function (s)
  (format " -> %s" (cadr (assoc s org-structure-template-alist))))

(defun org-easy-template-completion-function ()
  (when (looking-back "^[ \t]*<\\([^ \t]*\\)" (point-at-bol))
    (list
     (match-beginning 1) (point)
     'org-easy-template--completion-table
     :annotation-function 'org-easy-template--annotation-function
     :exclusive 'no)))

(defun add-easy-templates-to-capf ()
  (add-hook 'completion-at-point-functions
            'org-easy-template-completion-function nil t))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'add-easy-templates-to-capf)
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you should also say that it should be added to the `org-mode-hook`: `(defun add-easy-templates-to-capf ()
 (add-hook 'completion-at-point-functions 'org-easy-template-completion-function nil t))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'add-easy-templates-to-capf)`

Comment: Another minor thing: easy templates are still not listed after `<`. It doesn't bother me that much though, because I was more concerned with the actual completion.

Comment: You can either call `company-capf` after < interactively or set `company-minimum-prefix-length` to 0 to get the completion immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'haven't seen a direct answer to my question yet, here's a workaround using `yasnippet`: simply define a snippet for every easy template.

1. `M-x yas-new-snippet`
2. Insert name, key, and content like this:

```
    # -*- mode: snippet -*-
    # name: latex export
    # key: l_
    # --
    #+BEGIN_EXPORT latex
    $0
    #+END_EXPORT
```

3. Store it in `your_snippet_folder/org-mode`.

One could also use the key `<l` instead of `l_`, but this doesn't play well together with `company`.